# How do I know if someone has pulled my local git commits?

Tags: git

I'm using an svn-ish git workflow. Me and a couple developers all communicate though a central official repository.

Another developer is working on some sweeping changes, but he's got to do more tests before he can push to the official repo. I want to work on the project, but should base my changes on what he's done, rather than dealing with a whole slew of merge conflicts a couple of days from now.

My take on this is that he should commit his changes, and I should pull from his repository. This way, he gets to hold off on the big push, and I get to start using his code base.

I'm starting to worry... I love being able safely rebase commits that I haven't shared yet. But if people are allowed to pull from me, is `rebase` *ever* safe?

**Question:** Do git repositories know which commits have been pulled from them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if git repositories track what has been pulled, but I think the best option in this case is for the other developer to make a branch on the central repository, and push his changes to that branch as he goes.  That way, both of you can retain the ability to rebase safely before pushing, and you can pull from his branch as he goes.

Comment: Git has no (built in) way of tracking if someone has pulled from a repo. @vergenzt is right, have the other developer store their changes in a separate branch on your shared repository and periodically pull in their changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is on a different machine, for accessible, accessible using ssh, then you have connection information in the system logs, but that's about it.